# Hi can someone provide me a solution for soft link removal?

Tags: bash, linux-headers, pymol

```bash
sudo ln -s /home/user/Downloads/msms/msms.x86_64Linux2.2.6.1 /usr/local/bin/msms
```

I created a wrong softlink in the afore mentioned script which I need to remove. Can someone please provide a suitable solution. I also cannot find the path of the softlink.

Comment: Your statement has created the symlink `/usr/local/bin/msms/msms.x86_64Linux2.2.6.1` or the symlink `/usr/local/bin/msms`. So to undo: `sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/msms/msms.x86_64Linux2.2.6.1 /usr/local/bin/msms`.

Comment: This will find links starting with current location. `find . -type l -ls`